# Is it possible to customize the windows mobile BottomAppBar CommandBar?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

Any tricks to achieve below ?

1) add more than 4 AppBarButton in PrimaryCommands ?

2) change the primary AppBarButton icon with custom icon ?

3) add  custom icon to SecondaryCommands

Comment: This is one of those questions where I feel like someone basically just wants a summary of the documentation that they don't want to read. ;)

Comment: when i read documentation, it says not possible. So wanted to check, is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: If you had read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.appbarbutton.aspx) then you'd see that your #1, yes you can. #2, yes you can, and #3, [yes you can](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.commandbar) if you use the same thing learned from the docs for AppBarButton. There's even examples. Just saying.....

Comment: @Chris, the question is for Windows Phone 8.1, so the answer is No, No, No. Your documentation is for Windows 10, where this is possible.

Comment: The purpose of the app bar is to allow the user to quickly perform common actions. It is limited to 4 because there isn't enough real estate on the screen to handle any more, not only that, your app bar will become too crowded. If your view needs more than 4 app bar buttons, then it's probably doing too many things, consider re-thinking your design instead of fiddling with the app bar.